# scrollView not returning to correct position after keyboard hides

Tags: ios, xcode6, uinavigationbar, scrollview

I have a `Navigation View` (with the navigation bar at the top) with a `scrollView` inside it, and several text fields in the `scrollView`. I have the code set up so that when the keyboard is shown, the content moves up if it would hide the text field. The segue from the previous view is modal, so it slides up as a window popup (on the iPad).

Everything works well, but when when the keyboard is dismissed, the `scrollView` returns to a position higher than it originally began (the top fields become hidden behind the navigation bar at the top).

I found the issue is within this code:

```
func keyboardWillBeHidden() {
    println("Keyboard will be hidden")
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}
```

The line with the issue is `scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets`. I feel like I need to add `44` (the height of the navigation bar) to the top position of the `scrollView` so that it returns to its correct position, but I have no idea how to do this.

I also noticed that once this happens, the `scrollView` can no longer be scrolled (it seems stuck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before any editing begins, you can store your current scrollview.contentInset.

Later when editing ends, you can set the same to put it where it belonged. Don't use a hardcode 44.

Comment: Okay, so I captured the `scrollView.contentInset` in a variable in `keyboardWasShown()`, and then set both the `scrollView.contentInset` and `scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets` in `keyboardWillBeHidden()`.

Although this resolved my issue, I wonder if there is a better way to do this. Inside the storyboard, the `scrollView` is hidden behind the _placeholder_ navigation bar at the top; the `scrollView` is the full 600x600. I need to do this as the space required for the bar is taken into account at runtime but not in the storyboard.

Comment: I did the same but still not back to original position